# DO we have to ground transformer?

Tags: transformer, ground, grounding, electronic-ballast, ballast

I am using the transformer (a ballast), and its specfication sheet could be found here [ballast specification.](https://www.platt.com/CutSheets/Advance/71A6071.pdf) But on the data sheet, it doesn't says where we need to ground it. Usually, we would ground the transfomer on its outside case. However, since the data sheet doesn't say this, should I still ground it? I would perhaps connect a ground wire to the aluminum plate on the figures below. Would this work?

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Ask yourself what grounding achieves.

Comment: Did you read the label?

Comment: Yes, what does ground the core means

Comment: this is NOT creating a new "derived system" ... the output is grounded by the input.  grounding is neededin certain parts as specified by the label. grounding the core meets the voltage expectations of the insulation design

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It says on the label to ground the ballast core and the capacitor case.
I'd follow those directions.

The same is said here,
http://www.techlightusa.com/pdf/Replacement%20Ballast%20Kits.pdf

Comment: Yeah I think that would be OK.. The link I posted talks about breaking the enamel coating on the core with a star washer.  I'm not an AC power guy though... just following directions.

Answer (score 1):

If you add a ground, there is a probability to have 220 volts between "neutral" and ground at the output, especially in countries that are using non-polarized "schuko" type plugs and outlets (common in Europe).

[image]